# Find index from an array using regex with linq in c# .net

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I have an array which contains an elements as below

```
dec.02
Novemeber-2
Oct-6
.
.
.
```

Now suppose I want to find the index of dec.02
Suppose if an array in place of dec.02 there can be december-02.
So I want to use linq with regex which finds the index.
Date can be in any format

```
Regex will be (dec|december)\W*02
```

Can any one tell how to use regex with linq to find index from an array

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like that?

```
String[] data = new String[] {
  "dec.02",
  "Novemeber-2",
  "Oct-6",
  ...
};

// All the indexes
int[] indice = data
  .Select((line, index) => new {
     line = line,
     index = index})
  .Where(item => Regex.IsMatch(item.line, "Your regular expression"))
  .Select(item => item.index)
  .ToArray();
```

In case you want *1st* such index only (-1 if no index found):

```
// First index (or -1 if there's no such index)
int result = data
  .Select((line, index) => new {
     line = line,
     index = index})
  .Where(item => Regex.IsMatch(item.line, "Your regular expression"))
  .Select(item => item.index + 1)
  .FirstOrDefault() - 1;
```

Comment: No I want specific index of an element. above returns an array.

Comment: @user3138879: in that case use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `ToArray()`, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this can be a solution:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(dec|december)\W*02");
string[] dates = { "dec.02", "Novemeber-2", "Oct-6" };
int i = dates.Length - dates.SkipWhile(s => !regex.IsMatch(s)).Count(); // based-0 index
```